# Django truncate blog summary puzzle

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm building a blog in Django and realized something about my templates: The blog home page can display all the individual posts using the same format as a single blog, the only difference being that the text will be truncated for summary.

So what I did was define a template for displaying a blog that I'd include in the home page template:

```
{# blog/post_snippet.html #}
{% block content %}
    <h1> {{ post.title }} </h1>
    {% if post.author %}
        <h4>By {{ post.author.short_name }}</h4>
    {% endif %}

    {% if post.date_published %}
        <span>On {{ post.date_published }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    <p> {{ post.text | safe }} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

And this gets used inside a for loop in the "all posts" page:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% include 'blog/post_snippet.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem now is, when displaying all the posts, how do I tell the template system to truncate the blog text? One solution is to duplicate the template code but I don't want to do that. I also thought of inheriting, but my templates already inherit from a base template, plus I think inheriting will immediately insert all the content and so I won't be able to control the block placement??

I'm quite confused, actually. What's the best practice here?

Comment: Just use create 2 snippets `post_sinppet.html` and `short_post_snippet.html`. No other way I can remember of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to include post_snippet.html by passing a parameter to tell whether you want the truncated version of the text or not.

First, add a property to your model that will return a truncated version of the text, e.g.:

```
@property
def truncated_text():
    if len(self.text) > 100:
        return '%s...' % self.text[0:100]
    else:
        return self.text
```

In post_snippet.html, replace `{{ post.text | safe }}` by:

```
{% if truncated %}{{ post.truncated_text | safe }}{% else %}{{ post.text | safe }}{% endif %}
```

In the home page, you then just need to include post_snippet.html this way:

```
{% include 'blog/post_snippet.html' with truncated=True %}
```

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant answer!